# Plotly: How to remove the confidence interval values (from the error bar) in the tooltip?

Tags: r, tooltip, plotly

I am trying to remove the error bar values in the tooltip in an R Plotly graph.

I have tried playing around with the `hovertext` arguments from here: https://plot.ly/r/hover-text-and-formatting/ but can't get it to work.

I have these in a function where sometimes there are error bars, but most of the time there aren't (because I don't have the data) so the extra detail in the tooltip is not needed (as it just shows `+0/-0`).

With the example below, I would want it to just show `2010, 5` without the confidence intervals.

[image]

Any ideas?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

data <- tibble(x = c(2010, 2011, 2012),
               y = c(5, 6, 7),
               err_high = c(1, 1, 1),
               err_low = c(0.9, 1, 1.1))

#plotly graph
plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(data = data,  x = ~x, y = ~y,
            name = 'Actual', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers',
            line = list(shape = 'linear', width= 4, dash = 'solid'),
            error_y = list(type = "data", symmetric = FALSE, array = ~err_high, arrayminus = ~err_low)) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = 'Year'),
         yaxis = list (title = 'Value', rangemode = "tozero"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include

```
 text=paste(data$x, data$y, sep=', '),
 hoverinfo='text',
```

in `add_trace()` to get this:

**Plot:**

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

data <- tibble(x = c(2010, 2011, 2012),
               y = c(5, 6, 7),
               err_high = c(1, 1, 1),
               err_low = c(0.9, 1, 1.1))

#plotly graph
plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(data = data,  x = ~x, y = ~y,
            name = 'Actual', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers',
            line = list(shape = 'linear', width= 4, dash = 'solid'),
            text=paste(data$x, data$y, sep=', '),
            hoverinfo='text',
            error_y = list(type = "data", symmetric = FALSE, array = ~err_high, arrayminus = ~err_low)) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = 'Year'),
         yaxis = list (title = 'Value', rangemode = "tozero"))
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks!